# Codeigniter database error handling, trying to cover all of my possible scenarios

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to cover all my bases in the event my MYSQL database returns any errors (no rows, no connection, no table, etc...) when I'm making a query using `CodeIgniter 3`.

I have a helper function that returns the latitude and longitude based on a zip code provided.  It will always only return a single row (granted the record exits).  Here's my helper function as of now:

```
if (!function_exists('get_coordinates_from_zipcode')) {

    //gets latitude and longitude coordinates from supplied zipcode. Returns array
    function get_coordinates_from_zipcode($zipcode) {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->database();

        $query = $ci->db->get_where('Geo', array('zip =' => $zipcode))->row_array();

        if (!$query) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return $query;
        }
    }
    //* Fields returned from geolocation database *//
    /*  -zip
        -lat
        -lng
    // Returns false on error or no records
    */

}
```

And here is my `View` I'm using (passing `$data['array']` array to it from my `Controller`):

```
<?php if ($array == FALSE || !$array) : ?>
<?php echo "No data returned"; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php echo $array['zip'] . ' is located at ' . $array['lat'] . ' and ' . $array['lng']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works well if there are no rows, but I want to handle any other issues, such as more than one row (highly unlikely to happen), or if there's a problem connecting to the database or table.

I've tried this in my `Helper`

```
if ($ci->db->error()) {
        return $ci->db->error(); //
    } else {
        return $query;
}
```

When I do this, and purposely use an invalid zip code to pass the error to the view, `$ci->db->error()` always returns `array(2) { ["code"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(0) "" }` and is empty.  And of course I get errors that `Undefined index: lat` and `Undefined index: lng`

Should I be passing the `$ci-db->error()` array to the view and acting on it there?

I just want to make sure all my bases are covered.  In my mind I should be handling errors in the `Helper` function but the `error()` always seems to be empty even when there's an error (such as no rows, or no db connectivity, or no table by that name.

I feel like

```
if (!$query) {
    return FALSE;
} else {
    return $query;
}
```

inside my helper function won't cover all problems I could potentially have connecting to the database.

Comment: In your view, why do you apply PHP opening and closign tags to every line? You only need the first opening tag and the last closing tag.

Comment: I was planning on building an HTML table eventually using the data.  I'm really just trying to get this helper function working first before moving on to that and it was a quick way to output what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do the following:

```
if (!function_exists('get_coordinates_from_zipcode')) {

    //gets latitude and longitude coordinates from supplied zipcode. Returns array
    function get_coordinates_from_zipcode($zipcode) {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->database();

        if ($ci->db->conn_id === false) {
            return false; // connection couldn't be established
        }

        $query = $ci->db->get_where('Geo', array('zip =' => $zipcode));

        if ($query && $query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        return false;
    }
    //* Fields returned from geolocation database *//
    /*  -zip
        -lat
        -lng
    // Returns false on error or no records
    */

}
```

This way:

1. You test that query didn't return a FALSE result
2. You test that you are only getting 1 row
3. You make sure you have established a connection to the db (seems a bit overkill)

Please note: you should **always** check the value of `num_rows()` before attempting to access the result array/object. If there are no rows, then you will get undefined indexes when attempting to access the array.

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense.  In my view I'm doing this: `if ($array == FALSE || !$array)`.  That's redundant right?  I could just say `$array == FALSE`, right?

Comment: Yes it's now redundant!

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand the purpose of your helper here - If you dont use a model and if you bypass the controller here why do you even use Codeigniter at first ?

Now your question

if its possible i would create a model where you handle all the errors and try to `throw` them via Exceptions

a possible approach

Model

```
class Geo_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_coordinates_from_zipcode($zipcode = false)
    {
        if (!$zipcode)  throw new InvalidArgumentException('Zipcode should be set');

        $query = $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('Geo')
            ->where('zip', $zipcode)
            ->get();

        $arrError = $this->db->error();

        if (isset($arrError['message']) && !empty($arrError['message']))    throw new RuntimeException($arrError['message']);

        if ($query->num_rows() != 1)    throw new RuntimeException('Query - Number of rows should be 1');

        return $query->row_array();

    }
}
```

controller

```
class Geo extends CI_Controller
{

    public function coordinatesfromzipcode($zipcode)
    {
        $this->load->model('Geo_model');
        try
        {
            $row = $this->Geo_model->get_coordinates_from_zipcode($zipcode);
            //load your coordinates view
        }
        catch (Excepetion $e)
        {
            //load an error view or something like that...
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```